# Convergence of the periodization series in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm reading a paper using periodization of function, I know that for a given function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ we can define the periodization $\tilde{f}$ by $$\tilde{f}(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f(x+k)$$ which is obviously a periodic function and belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{T})$. However, in the paper the author took a function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and just said that he can define by the same way the periodization function which is convergent in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$. I don't even understand why the periodization is well defined in this case and how the serie might converge in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$.

Comment: What is your $f$ ?  $L^2(\Bbb{T})\subset L^1(\Bbb{T})$ and for $f \ge 0$, $\|\sum_k f(.+k)\|_{L^1[0,1]} = \|f\|_{L^1(\Bbb{R})}$ (even when the latter norm is $=\infty$) thus with $f(x)=x^{-2/3}1_{x >1}$ it fails

Comment: Anyway even if the function isn't nonegative we also have $$||\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f(.+k)||_{L^1(\mathbb{T})}\leqslant ||f||_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}.$$
My problem is in how manner he thought define the periodization of $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00120268/document
it's the lastest definition in page 3

Comment: We can't periodize any $L^2$ function, that's why I ask what $f$ you want to look at. If it is in $L^1\cap L^2$ then it converges in $L^1[0,1]$ but it doesn't have to converge in $L^2[0,1]$

Comment: What is $\mathbb{T}$?

Comment: Just because $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|dx < \infty$ does not mean that $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} f(x+k)$ is finite for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (or even well defined as a sum). We might have $f(n)=1$ for all integers $n$, or $f(n)=(-1)^n$ for all integers $n$.

Comment: $\mathbb{T}$ means the Torus and  we know that for every $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}),\;\tilde{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$

Comment: So "the Torus" has no ambiguity?

Comment: @Michael $\mathbb T$ stands for the torrus $\mathbb R /\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Some decay condition is needed if you wish to periodise elements of $L^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ then $$\sum_n f(x+n) = g\in L^1[0,1]$$
$\hat{f}$ is continuous and  $$c_k(g) = \hat{f}(k)$$
Iff $\sum_k |\hat{f}(k)|^2<\infty$ then
$$ g=\sum_k \hat{f}(k) e^{2i\pi k x} \in L^2[0,1]\cap L^1[0,1]$$
This is what your paper is using

Comment: How are you defining $\sum_n f(x+n)$ when it yields $\sum_n 1$ or $\sum_n (-1)^n$?

Comment: The series converges in $L^1[0,1]$, we don't care of the pointwise value (same for the Fourier series below)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Can you illuminate what $\mathbb{T}$ means?  Just saying "the Torus" means nothing to me.  It must be some subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and I would like to know what subset is being talked about.

Comment: @Michael: $\mathbb{T}$ usually means $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, or the unit circle.

Comment: I understand very well what you're saying @reuns, and it's obviously right, howver if you look at the definition the athor took a function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and it's not a typesting mistake because the author really needs all his results arround $L^2$ functions., so I'm still at the same starting point

Comment: @copper.hat : "the unit circle" is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but $\tilde{f}(x)$ is defined for (almost all) real values $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  I assume either $\mathbb{T}=[0,1)$ or $x \in [0, 1)\leftrightarrow \omega \in [0, 2\pi)$ and we have some implicit mapping in which case we perhaps have $\hat{f}(\omega) = \tilde{f}(g(\omega))$.

Comment: But wht if $\sum_k |\hat{f}(k)|^2=\infty$?

Comment: @Michael: The question is worded a little sloppily. For example. not all square integrable functions have a periodisation. Typically there is some 'sufficient decay at infinity'' condition.

Comment: I agree the paper is wrong as it is, I think it is implicitly replacing $f$ by $f_n=f \ast n e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}$ and let $n\to \infty$, this way $\hat{f}_n$ is rapidly decreasing and you are no afraid to do the computation in p.5 @Slouma (this is a standard procedure to prove a bound on the dense subspace, extending it to the whole space, here the random variable $\|\sum f(\rho(x+k)\|_{L^2[0,1]}^2$ obtained from $f\in L^2(\Bbb{R})$)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @reuns

Answer (score 1):

People have said in comments that periodization doesn't work for an arbitrary $f\in L^2(\Bbb R)$ but I don't see a counterexample. Let $f(t)=\frac1{|t|+1}$; then $f\in L^2(\Bbb R)$ but the sum defining $\tilde f$ converges pointwise to $+\infty$ at every point. (Hence Fatou's Lemma shows that the $L^2(\Bbb T)$ norm of the partial sums tends to $+\infty$.)

(I'm told that a similar counterexample has already been posted; in fact, as stated above, I don't see it here...)

Comment: I gave a counter-example with $x^{-2/3}1_{x > 1}$

Comment: @reuns Oh. I didn't see that - looking again I still don't...